# Haskell: effective computation of recursively-defined function values

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming, complexity-theory, recurrence

I want to compute the recursively-defined function values `r(i,j)`, which are defined by

```
r i j  | i<0 || j<0   = 0
       | i==0 && j==0 = 1
       | otherwise    = (i-1) * r (i-2) j + r (i-1) (j-1)
```

Obviously, the `NxN` table of these coefficients can be computed in `O(N^2)`.
Unfortunately, the straightforward evaluation, like

```
[[r i j | j <-[0..50]]| i <- [0..50]]
```

is performed in screamingly ineffective way (exponential complexity). Apparently, Haskell builds the entire recursion tree for each `r i j` and ignores the values of previously computed `r (i-1) (j-1)` etc.

What is the elegant and effective way to compute such a table?

Comment: ... I don't know haskell but it seems you want dynamic programming. (googleit)

Comment: You want memoization, see http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Memoization

Comment: if you want just a single value, rather than the whole table you might want to calculate a generating function for the recursive series. I'm no expert on this but I once heard about that in a lecture about discrete math/combinatorics. maybe the fellas at math.stackexchange.com are able to help you in that regard. Words I associate with that kind of math is "umbral calculus", "gosper algorithm" and "Zeilberger algorithm". Maybe it is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As FUZxxl says, this is a memoisation question.

```
r i j | i < 0 || j < 0 = 0
      | otherwise      = rss !! i !! j

rss = [[r' i j | j <- [0..]] | i <- [0..]]
  where r' 0 0 = 1
        r' i j = (i-1) * r (i-2) j + r (i-1) (j-1)
```

If you need an explicit table of precisely the values up to 50, you can use `take 51 (map (take 51) rss)`, or `[[r i j | j <-[0..50]]| i <- [0..50]]` as you mentioned. Otherwise you can just call `r` or reference `rss` directly.

Comment: This is still slower than it could be though, since access will be O(i+j). If you limit yourself to a given size, an array would be more appropriate (lazy array, not unboxed) for O(1) access, and if you want unlimited, a trie of trie (IntMap) should still be faster than a list of list.

Comment: And if you are tasteful enough to hate the array library API then use vector instead.